# Analytical derivation of convolution and multiplication implement of time-domain signal

Tags: filter-design, convolution, frequency-domain, time-domain

I have a system model as shown in figure 1. I want to change the model to a new schematic as in figure 2. How to analytically derive the filter $H_2$ if all parameters are known?
[image]

I guess that we will face the difficulty of exchange between convolution and multiplication operation whether in time or in frequency domain. The output in figure 1, $y_a = (x*h_1)^3$ and that of in figure 2, $y_b = x^3*h_2$ ($*$ being convolution). But I do not know how to solve it.

Comment: Assuming that $[.]^3$ means "to the third power" I don't think this can be done. It's not an LTI system

Comment: Before anyone writes a long, analysis-heavy answer: What are your conditions on $x$, what's your signal model? Single tone, many tones, line spectrum, continuous-spectrum? What's the restrictions on $H_1$? FIR, IIR, and if the latter, what conditions on the RoC need to apply to the second system?

Comment: @MarcusMüller In my model, x can be any kind of signals, inncluding single tone or wide-band signal., H1 is an FIR filter. The filter H2 should be a causal, FIR (or IIR). Thanks.

Comment: uff, I don't think then what you want is possible; it's not possible to find a linear system that has all the same effects as a different linear system before a nonlinear operation.

Comment: what is y_0 and y_0'?

Comment: @GideonGenadiKogan I think these are just the names given in the figures to denote the "intermediate" signals, so $y_0 = x*h_1$ and $y'_0=x^3$.

Comment: @MarcusMüller why the different notation though?

Comment: don't know, and honestly, it's not a really bad notation, why does it matter?